# Build simple LTspice MOSFET model for textbook examples

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, modeling

I am trying to build a simple MOSFET model (very simple, no parasitic capacitance, gate leakage, ohmic contact...) using LTspice to simulate school textbook example, but I don't know how to switch between cutoff, triode, and saturation region.

MOSFET model in saturation I build
[image: MOSFET model of saturation region]

Or is using its build-in model more recommended?

Comment: Use nested `if(x,y,z)` statements, maybe?  Or you can alternatively include 3 parallel current sources; one for each region with if-statements which result in zero when not in the corresponding region.  I would say the built-in models are better because they include the B-D and B-S diodes and have GMINs to prevent convergence failure.  At the minimum you should include a `1t` resistor across your current source(s).

Comment: Also, instead of doing `V(G)-V(S)` you can simply write `V(G,S)` instead.  You can also use `**` for exponentiation instead of `pow()`.  So like `V(G,S)**2` gets you \$(V_{GS})^2\$.  Speaking of which, your equation seems to be missing \$V_{th}\$.

Comment: Very helpful. I will try. Thank you.